# Python Class: Unable to increment counter of trips since maintenance when switching True to Falsenor resetting counter to zero after Repair

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
"""
class vehicle:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, weight):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.weight = weight
        self.NeedsMaintenance = False
        self.TripsSinceMaintenance = int(0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ": " + str(self.__dict__)

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model + ' ' + self.weight
        return long_name.title()

    def increment_TripsSinceMaintenance(self, Trips):
        self.TripsSinceMaintenance_reading += Trips

    def update_TripsSinceMaintenance(self, TripsRecorded):
        if TripsRecorded >= self.TripsSinceMaintenance_reading:
            self.TripsSinceMaintenance_reading = TripsRecorded

    def read_TripsSinceMaintence(self):
        print("This car has made " + str(self.TripsSinceMaintenance_reading) + " trips up to now.")

class car(vehicle):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, weight, drive, stop,):
        vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, weight, )
        self.drive = drive
        self.stop = stop
        self.TripsSinceMaintenance = int(110)

    def drive(self):
        self.isDriving = True
        if  not self.isDriving & self.TripsSinceMaintenance <= int(100):
            self.TripsSinceMaintenance_reading += self.Trips


    def stop(self):
        self.isDriving = False
        if not self.isDriving or self.TripsSinceMaintenance >= int(100):
            self.isDriving == True


    def repair(self):
        if self.TripsSinceMaintenance >= int(100): 
            self.update_TripsSinceMaintenance = 0 & self.stop == False


my_tesla = car('tesla', 'model s', 2016, '70k', False, False)
print(my_tesla)

<class '__main__.car'>: {'make': 'tesla', 'model': 'model s', 'year': 2016, 'weight': '70k', 'NeedsMaintenance': False, 'TripsSinceMaintenance': 110, 'drive': False, 'stop': False}
```

The print correctly shows the car and its details but does not do exactly what I need.  I need the counter of TripsSinceMaintenance initially set to 0 in parent class to increase when Switching isDriving from true to false  And then when TripsSinceMaintenance exceeds 100, the NeedsMaintenance boolean should be set to true and not false as it is initially set.

The "Repair" method also needs to reset the TripsSinceMaintenance to zero, and NeedsMaintenance to false.

I am not sure if I need to import Counter or whether I have the wrong method to switch True to False and many searches have not helped. Fairly new to Python so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to use the keyword “and” instead of “&” in your conditions

Comment: Thank you.  Any suggestions for the other points?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, weight):
        self.make = make
        self.year = year
        self.model = model
        self.weight = weight
        self.NeedsMaintenance = False
        self.TripsSinceMaintenance = 0

    def set_make(self, make):
        self.make = make

    def set_model(self, model_type):
        self.model = model_type

    def set_year(self, year):
        self.year = year

    def set_weight(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight

    def repair(self):
        self.TripsSinceMaintenance = 0
        self.NeedsMaintenance = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ": " + str(self.__dict__)


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(
        self,
        make,
        model,
        year,
        weight,
    ):
        Vehicle.__init__(
            self,
            make,
            model,
            year,
            weight,
        )
        self.isDriving = False

    def drive(self):
        self.isDriving = True
        self.TripsSinceMaintenance += 1
        if self.TripsSinceMaintenance >= 100:
            self.NeedsMaintenance = True

    def stop(self):
        self.isDriving = False
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did find the answer a while back but hopefully this may help someone in the future as well.